# How to run Docker container in it's own network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Today I switched from "Docker Toolbox" to "Docker for Mac", because Docker now has finally write-access to my `User` directory (which doesn't worked with "Docker Toolbox") - Yay!

But this change also includes that all containers now running under my localhost and not under Docker's IP as before (e.g. `192.168.99.100`).

Since my `localhost` listens to various ports by default (80, 443, ...) and I don't want to always add new created ports, that doesn't conflict with the standard one's, to my local dev domains (e.g. `example.dev:8443`), I wonder how to run my containers as before.

I read about `network` configs and tried a lot of things (creating a new host network, exposing ports with an IP in front of it, ...), but didn't got it working.

What kind of config do I need to run my app container with the IP `192.168.99.100`? Thats my `docker-compose.yml` so far.

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - redis
      - memcached
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 22:22
      - 3000:3000
      - 3001:3001
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app/
      - /tmp/debug/:/tmp/debug/
      - ./:/docker/
    volumes_from:
      - storage
    # cap and privileged needed for slowlog
    cap_add:
      - SYS_PTRACE
    privileged: true
    env_file:
      - etc/environment.yml
      - etc/environment.development.yml

  mysql:
    build:
      context: docker/mysql/
      dockerfile: MariaDB-10
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes_from:
      - storage
    volumes:
      - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - /tmp/debug/:/tmp/debug/
    env_file:
      - etc/environment.yml
      - etc/environment.development.yml

  redis:
    build: docker/redis/
    volumes_from:
      - storage
    env_file:
      - etc/environment.yml
      - etc/environment.development.yml

  memcached:
    build: docker/memcached/
    volumes_from:
      - storage
    env_file:
      - etc/environment.yml
      - etc/environment.development.yml

  storage:
    build: docker/storage/
    volumes:
      - /storage
```

Comment: check this out https://forums.docker.com/t/host-excluded-from-bridge-network/12015/11

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare "networks:" for each of your services:

e.g.

```
version: '2'
services:
    app:
        image: xxxx:xxx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        networks:
            - my-network
    mysql:
        image: xxxx:xxx
        networks:
            - my-network
networks:
    my-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Then from side your app configuration, you can use "mysql" as the hostname of database server.

Answer (score -1):

You can define a network in your compose file, then add any services to the network.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

But I would suggest you just use different ports now that you are running natively. I.e. 8080:80

Comment: That's what I've tried, but this doesn't work either, because the Ports in a bridged network are forwarded to localhost.